# Version info on a server application

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-xe2, versioning

I am trying to include version info in a Delphi service application.

From Delphi Project Options /Version info i tried to insert a version info such
4.3.2.1

but after building my service i see 1.0.0.0 on file properties.
any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Version information can be set for each target.  You can set the current target in the Project Manager under Build Configurations.

If you set the version in one configuration (like Debug) and build another one (like Release), you won't see these changes in your executable.

You can set it using the drop down at the top of the Project Options dialog.  I usually select "All Configurations".

If you are using the default output directories, you might want to make sure you are looking at the correct executable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. WHat you say is clear to me and i already made all those checks. So you confirm that "in principle" the server exe shuol take the version info as a normal project?

Comment: Another suggestion: Try removing the .res file (with Delphi closed), start Delphi (it will be recreated) and try entering the version information again.